# MeteorJS dynamic query

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-collection2

Is it possible to build queries dynamically? For instance, I need to build a function like this:

`var dynamicQuery = function(collectionName) {
    return collectionName.find({});
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

**pass the collection itself**

```js
var dynamicQuery = function(Collection) {
  return Collection.find();
};

dynamicQuery(Posts);
```

**pass the name of the collection**

```js
var dynamicQuery = function(name) {
  var root = Meteor.isClient ? window : global;
  var Collection = root[name];
  return Collection.find();
};

dynamicQuery('Posts');
```

Recommended reading: [collections by reference](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/collections-by-reference).

Comment: Yes, thank you @David Weldon, my silly mistake was to send the collection as string instead of object